# Spacy / sciSpacy Version Issues

Tags: python, nlp, version-control, conda, spacy

I am trying to use sciSpacy to build a processing pipeline, and am encountering version issues.

I have created a virtual conda environment with the packages installed; scispacy 0.5.1 requires spacy 3.4.4 installation, which is not the most recent version.

This becomes an issue when attempting to load a pipeline:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_sm")
```

```
RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy.Tagger.v2' in function registry 'architectures'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is installed in your environment.

Available names: spacy-legacy.CharacterEmbed.v1, spacy-legacy.EntityLinker.v1, spacy-legacy.HashEmbedCNN.v1, spacy-legacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v1, spacy-legacy.MishWindowEncoder.v1, spacy-legacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1, spacy-legacy.Tagger.v1, spacy-legacy.TextCatBOW.v1, spacy-legacy.TextCatCNN.v1, spacy-legacy.TextCatEnsemble.v1, spacy-legacy.Tok2Vec.v1, spacy-legacy.TransitionBasedParser.v1, spacy.CharacterEmbed.v2, spacy.EntityLinker.v1, spacy.HashEmbedCNN.v2, spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2, spacy.MishWindowEncoder.v2, spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2, spacy.PretrainCharacters.v1, spacy.PretrainVectors.v1, spacy.SpanCategorizer.v1, spacy.Tagger.v1, spacy.TextCatBOW.v2, spacy.TextCatCNN.v2, spacy.TextCatEnsemble.v2, spacy.TextCatLowData.v1, spacy.Tok2Vec.v2, spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1, spacy.TorchBiLSTMEncoder.v1, spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2
```

Does anyone have experience of similar issues or is aware of a way to update the `spacy.Tagger.v1` function within the registry?

I have upgraded pip and tried to create a new environment, reinstalling packages with latest versions.

Comment: `spacy.Tagger.v2` was added in spacy v3.3.0, so it sounds like something has gone wrong with your installation. Try installing scispacy from scratch in a new environment without installing spacy first.